# Position of INET sink node defined by $ParameterName is not updated

Tags: omnet++, inet

I set up a wireless sensor network as below.**(Emphasis on sink node definition)**

```
import  inet.physicallayer.wireless.apsk.packetlevel.ApskScalarRadioMedium;                                          
import inet.node.inet.SensorNode;
network SensorNetwork
{      
int numNodes = default(15);   
string interfaceTableModule = default("interfaceTable");    
int areaX @unit(m) = 500m;             
int areaY @unit(m) = 500m;            
int sinkX @unit(m) = int (this.areaX*(0.5));                
int sinkY @unit(m) = this.areaY;                
@display("bgb=$areaX,$areaY;bgu=m");

submodules:
    sink: SensorNode {
      @display("i=device/antennatower;p=$sinkX,$sinkY");
    }

    node[numNodes]: SensorNode;

    radioMedium: ApskScalarRadioMedium {
        @display("p=45,79");
    }
}
```

I would like to highlight the fact that sink position is given by parameters. When I run the project, and go to check the details related to the mobility submodule of the sink node I find that the last position coordinate is (`lastPosition (Coord) (0, 0, 0) m`) whereas it should have the current coordinate of the sink node in the network.
When I delete the parameter and give the numeric values to X and Y from  `@display("p=500,500;i=device/antennatower");`,the position is well updated as (`lastPosition (Coord) (500, 500, 0) m`).

**How to fix it?**

Please, your advice is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of omnet you ar using?

Comment: Hi @Rudi. I'm using omnetpp-6.0pre11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I try to reproduce this (I'm using omnetpp-pre13 development branch + inet 4.4 development branch), I get an error:

`Mobility position is not a finite number after initialize (x=-nan,y=-nan,z=-nan) -- in module (inet::StationaryMobility)`

However, you can specify node positions via the mobility module in the .INI file (`initialX`, `initialY`, `initialZ` parameters), which I think is the intended way. You can use variables for the position there as well.

Comment: Hi @adamgeorge309 .  I need to variate the sink node position in my C++ code that's why I prefer to define it parametrically. However, I have already done as you suggest by defining the node position via `constraintAreaMinX` , `constraintAreaMaxX` ....parameters

Comment: If you need to change the position in C++ code, then that can be done by creating a mobility model for the position-related code.

Comment: Also, I think the NED variable parameters should be working nevertheless, so it might eventually get fixed.

Comment: These questions are similar and might be helpful:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51425152/omnet-how-to-set-node-position-manually-in-inet-4-0?rq=1
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51450904/omnet-how-to-move-node-in-a-discrete-nxn-space-in-inet-4-0?rq=1

Comment: Yes, the NED variable is fixed and I can work with this. Only the update in the network is not done. e.g When I used the DataLinkVisualizer to see the Activity at the `service` level, the arrow is still oriented to the point of coordinate `(0,0,0)m` whereas my sink node is occupying another position in the network.